# Is there a way to merge two fasta files together using Linux?

Tags: linux, merge, fasta

I have been trying to get two fasta files I have to be merged together as one but when I try using the cat command it doesn't give me what I want.
What I want is

```
input:
fasta_1: AASSAA
fasta_2: FFGT
output:
fasta_merged: AASSAAFGT
```

but when I use the cat command it gives me this

```
input:
fasta_1: AASSAA
fasta_2: FFGT
output:
fasta_merged: AASSAA
              FFGT
```

Is there a way to mix the two together without using cat?

Answer (score 0):

Use paste:

```
paste -d '' fasta_1 fasta_2 > fasta_3
```

Set the delimiter to nothing and then join the lines of fasta_1 with fasta_2, outputting the result to fasta_3

Answer (score 0):

Use a Perl one-liner to remove the terminal newline, and `cat`, together in parens:

```
( perl -pe 'chomp if eof' fasta_1 ; cat fasta_2 ) > fasta_merged
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`chomp` : Remove the terminal input record separator (newline on *NIX).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

---

Note that what you have does not look like FASTA format, but a file with raw sequences. Also, the current answer will not work with proper FASTA file, since the terminal newline is important there: the next sequence has to start with `>` on a new line.